# Unable to inject items into a function using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, items

```
<div class='basket__center_item' ng-repeat="item in baskeItems" >
    <img class='basket__center_foto' src="img/{{item.foto}}" />
    <h4 class='basket__center_name' > {{item.name}}</h4>
    <p class='basket__center_price' > price is {{ item.price }} $</p>
    <input class='basket__center_amount' type='number' min="1" max='2000'
           value="{{item.amount}}" ng.model='item.amount' ng-click='totalFnc(item)' />
</div>
```

When I call `totalFnc(item)`, I'm unable to pass my items to it. It gives me: "item undefined". Why is this happening?

Comment: You should try to explain your problem better in order to get some help.

Comment: Check your spelling on `baskeItems`

Comment: @georgeawg: I think that `baskeItems` is actually correct (although it is misspelled), otherwise he wouldn't see the element where he calls the `totalFnc(item)` as the ng-repeat would not render anything (including that element). Moreover, the OP would have also complained about `item.name` and `item.price` not being shown :)

Comment: @bosch In that case we need to see how `totalFnc` is handling `item` because `ng-repeat` can call a function with `item`.

Comment: @Enough can you add the code of totalFnc() here,so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `$index`  to your `totelFnc()` function:

```
ng-click='totalFnc($index)'
```

Then retrieve your object in your controller by:

```
$scope.totalFnc() = function( id ) {
    var myItem = $scope.baskeItems[ id ];
}
```